# Validator on OneStepCheckout in review step

Tags: onepage-checkout, validation, ce-1.8.0.0

From my module I added a block with a checkbox into `checkout_onepage_review`. Now I could like to make sure this checkbox was selected. Therefor I am observing the `sales_order_place_after` event where I can capture the result.

How do I use the the Magento JavaScript validator in the last checkout step (review).

If I add `class="checkbox required-entry"` nothing happens because the button uses `review.save()` which does not call the validator. Also it does not send my checkbox value...

Answer (score 0):

rather then observing event you can also add validation `class="checkbox required-entry"`

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but nothing happens if I don't check the box.

Comment: but after sales_order_place_after you can not go the back to the form because order is already placed but you can also check with sales_order_place_before to check checkbox is check or not

Comment: Problem with `required-entry` is that the button function  `review.save()` does not use a validator because normally there is no need to. I got to add this somehow...

Comment: you can check with this event sales_order_place_before put observer and check check-box is check or not

Comment: follow this link http://www.techflirt.com/magento-event-observer-hook-in-magento/ it may help you

Comment: if you find my answer helpful then accept it @PiTheNumber